# Is there a particular function to retrieve then delete random array element?

Tags: ruby

I know I can do this in a couple of steps, but was wondering if there is a function which can achieve this.

I want to array#sample, then remove the element which was retrieved.

Answer (score 28):

How about this:

```
array.delete_at(rand(array.length))
```

Comment: This is essentially two steps (`rand(array.length)` and `array.delete_at(idx)`). OP did ask for only one method, but probably one of the simplest ways to perform this kind of operation in Ruby.

Comment: I know this is ten years old, but just gotta say how much I love it when I find elegant solutions to my problems.  Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

Another inefficient one, but super obvious what's going on:

```
array.shuffle.pop
```

What would be nice would be a destructive version of the sample method on Array itself, something like:

```
class Array
  def sample!
    delete_at rand length
  end
end
```

Comment: Bottom line: something like your second example (although in the language in which the interpreter is implemented) should be part of the core Array implementation. I would probably call it something like `delete_sample!` or something, though, as I find it a bit more obvious what it does. :-)

Comment: It needs to be array.shuffle!.pop

Comment: If you go for this option, and you want to remove the item from original array you better do `array.shuffle!.pop`, or else your array will remain as it was. Doing `shuffle` without bang (!) will just give you another array to `pop` from.

Answer (score 2):

Linuxios's has it perfect. Here is another example:

```
array = %w[A B C]
item_deleted = array.delete_at(1)
```

Here it is in irb:

```
1.9.2p0 :043 > array = %w[A B C]
 => ["A", "B", "C"] 
1.9.2p0 :044 > item_deleted = array.delete_at(1)
 => "B" 
1.9.2p0 :045 > array
 => ["A", "C"] 
1.9.2p0 :047 > item_deleted
 => "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the rand(array.length) approach already mentioned, could be this one

```
element = array.delete array.sample
```

Eksample:

```
>> array   = (1..10).to_a
>> element = array.delete array.sample
>> array   # => [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>> element # => 3
```

This is also a set of two operations, but at least you won't have to move away from the array itself.

Comment: This one may be less efficient than the others (delete requires a search) but it's obvious at a glance what it's doing.

Comment: This is true, but I think it's a bit more readable than using `rand`, as there already is a way to find a random element in an array. Also, we don't have to drag in the length of the array, which is something we really shouldn't need to care about. :-)

Comment: This approach runs into problems when you have duplicates in an array because delete removes all by equality. For instance in this example, if sample gets the "a".  `["a","a","b"].delete sample` ==> deleted: "a", remaining: ["b"]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to sample a number of items and the remove those from the original array:

```
array = (1..10).to_a

=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

grab = array.sample(4)

=> [2, 6, 10, 5]

grab.each{ |a| array.delete a }

=> [2, 6, 10, 5]

array
=> [1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This only works if your original array is full of unique values, otherwise you'd be deleting all '2's