# Pick random element from an array and remove it

Tags: ruby

I would like to pick an random element from an array, remove it from the array, and then return the element.

I can use `sample` to get an element, `index` to find where it is, and then `delete_at` to remove it, but is there a better way?

Comment: Where's your code showing what you've tried to this point? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I wrote it in natural language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a particular function to retrieve then delete random array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988525/is-there-a-particular-function-to-retrieve-then-delete-random-array-element)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
array.delete_at(rand(array.length))
```

This seems right, and I guess it works best.

**EDIT:** This same answer is here: [Is there a particular function to retrieve then delete random array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988525/is-there-a-particular-function-to-retrieve-then-delete-random-array-element) so I'd go with this :D

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer at all. It's clear and simple, even if it's not the cutest. :)

Answer (score 21):

Most beautiful solution:

```
array.delete(array.sample)
```

Comment: I like it. Delete and return a random element. I was too fixed on indices.

Comment: Warning: If you use use this on an array with duplicate values, it will eliminate every duplicate not just one.